# Jquery UI slider that changes the values of two different elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a group of jquery sliders setup that change the opacity of different layers of an image.  I'm trying to figure out how to have it so one slider will change the opacity of two divs, but in opposite directions.  So while one's value moves towards 0% the other is moving towards 100%.

I have it set up like this but I'm not really sure how to modify it:

```
$('#slider3').slider({ 
    min: 0, 
    max: 1, 
    step: 0.01, 
    value: 1,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    slide: function(e,ui){
                 $('#nebula').css('opacity', ui.value)

         }                
    });
```

BIG thanks in advance to anyone who can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to use `1 - ui.value` for the other image opacity. For example, if your other image had an id of `inverse`:

```
$('#slider3').slider({ 
    min: 0, 
    max: 1, 
    step: 0.01, 
    value: 1,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    slide: function(e,ui){
        var val = ui.value;
        $('#nebula').css('opacity', val);
        $('#inverse').css('opacity', 1 - val);
    }                
});
```

Comment: wow, that's exactly what I was looking for, that's fantastic that it was so simple.  Basically the way I had it before I could only get things moving in one direction.  Thanks very much.

Comment: @loriensleafs awesome! You're welcome! I'll cleanup my answer a bit if you would kindly mark this answer as correct :)